# How do I find the position of the first 0 looking backwards in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have a really long array like this:

```
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]}
```

I also have a maximum position where I can look, like 6, making a slice of the array that returns this:

```
sliceLocation = 6
```

returning:

```
np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,1]}
```

now I want to write a piece of code that slices the array and then searches for the first 0 inside this array coming from the back, in this case returning `4` as a viable position in a quick and efficient time. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example but i dont understand what you want to do with the rest of the array arr.

```
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1])
sliceLocation = 6

arr = arr[:sliceLocation+1]
idx = np.where(arr==0)[0][-1]
```

> idx = 4

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
sliceLocation = 6
sliceLocation-list(arr)[:sliceLocation+1][::-1].index(0)

4
```

How it works: It slices the array, changes it to a list, reverses it, find the index of first 0 and by subtracting it from sliceLocation it gives the final result